# Effect of wheel location on center of gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

So, my kids are in Cub Scouts and are racing in the Pinewood Derby for the first time. After a thorough read-through of the rules, there is nothing prohibiting a racer from shifting the rear axle (or front axle) forwards or backwards.

According to [my research](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-RjJtO51ykY) the most important factor in speed for the race is shifting the center of gravity backwards without causing the car to wheelie and lose control.

What then would be the overall effect of shifting the rear axle as far backwards as possible (about 1/4th inch) before the wheel would extend outside of the limited parameters.

Similarly, what would be the effect of shifting the front axle forward up to 3/4 inch or backwards on the center of gravity?

Answer (score 0):

Having run many, many pinewood derby races, as a mechanical engineer I can say that the primary determinant of success was the ability of the car to track straight enough so as not to drag against the guide strip during the downhill run. Cars that dragged lost their races and those that did not were the winners.

Aerodynamics did not matter, nor did carving off wood and then ballasting the car with lead weights back to spec, adding fins, wings or whatnot.

Since the races I ran involved multiple runs so every car ran a race against every other car in the pool, the other determinant of success was the ability to run a race without having the wheels and axles getting bonked out of square so the car no longer tracked straight.

Comment: Yes - I've had several swear by rail-riding. However, our Pack is forbidden from canting or angling the axles this year. Further, According to the research of Dr. Scott Acton, a Physicist from Ball Aerospace, aside from rail-riding, Weight location and the center of gravity is the most significant factor in the success of a derby car (as explained in the video) and gives an advantage of about 4.6 carlengths. Aerodynamics only provides an advantage of about 1.4 carlengths. Ultimately though, my question isn't about how to win the pinewood derby, but about center of gravity.

Comment: I'll have to watch that video then! -NN